# Are there ways to break down Frequent Itemsets support into which categories (from a categorical variable column) contributed to the support the most

Tags: python

Using the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori, association_rules
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Extended data
data = {'ProductID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        'Description': ['This is a great product for all users.',
                        'Users love this amazing and fantastic product.',
                        'Another product description for testing.',
                        'product is great',
                        'New product description for users.',
                        'Another fantastic product for testing.',
                        'Great product with unique features.',
                        'Test the fantastic features of our new product.',
                        'Product description for international users.',
                        'Exciting product for global customers.',
                        'great product with unique features'],
        'Country': ['USA', 'UK', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Australia', 'UK', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Germany', 'India', 'India']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Preprocess the text data
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
excluded_keywords = set([])  # Add the specific keywords to exclude

def preprocess_text(text):
    if isinstance(text, str):  # Check if the value is a non-null string
        text = text.lower()
        text = ''.join([c for c in text if c.isalnum() or c.isspace()])
        tokens = text.split()
        tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop_words and word not in excluded_keywords]
        return tokens
    else:
        return []

df['ProcessedDescription'] = df['Description'].apply(preprocess_text)

# Transform the data into a list of lists (transactions)
transactions = df['ProcessedDescription'].tolist()

# Use TransactionEncoder to transform the transactions into a boolean DataFrame
te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(transactions).transform(transactions)
word_frequencies = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
display(word_frequencies)


# Find frequent itemsets
frequent_itemsets = apriori(word_frequencies, min_support=0.2, use_colnames=True)
frequent_itemsets.sort_values(by='support', ascending=False, inplace=True)

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
print("Frequent Itemsets:")
display(frequent_itemsets)
```

with above script, i should obtain the below output:
[image]

we can see that the word has a support of 0.272727 and appear 3 times the description. These description came from 2 x UK and once from US.
Are there ways to configure the output such that it shows the contribution of the support coming from which category (country in this example)

eg.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might try
[LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation).
There are libraries available for modeling
[large](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) and
[small](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html)
datasets.

Choose a parameter of `2` or `3` and verify it can reliably
segment your product IDs into several topics.
Then ask for about `11` topics and hope you get a 1:1 product:topic mapping.
Ask the model for a few more topics if you really want to encourage
a product to get its own topic.

The nice thing about LDA is it's easy to explain to stake holders,
as the model is simply keywords that can be sorted by importance
(sorted by their weights).